# Doubts in Laravel

Tags: laravel, lamp, laravel-7

I was learning Laravel, I felt doubts regarding to the same.

1. Do we need APACHE server for Laravel? Because, without my LAMP server ON, I could do php artisan serve
2. Laravel server is working on HTTP, I wish to work it on HTTPS server.

Can someone help me in above questions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

the php artisan serve is more for testing purpose, to start a development server, so you build you application as fast as you can to test it, but its *not* for running it to production.

and for your second question, with apache you can solve that, but if you still want to use it with the php artisan serve, you can use ngrok like this

```php
cd <path-to-ngrok>
./ngrok http localhost:8000
```

https://ngrok.com/

Comment: So, can u plz guide me how to run Laravel on LAMP or Apache?
I am getting too much confused about it, please sorry about it.

Comment: First result on Google for `linux+apache`: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-laravel-on-ubuntu-for-apache/